# Why is terminal providing me with zero results for this .py script?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am learning unittest and am trying to work on the following two .py scripts but when i run on terminal it shows "ran 0 tests". What am i doing wrong?

sanity.py

```
def firstname(name):
    return name.title()
```

and then the second

sanitycheck.py

```
import unittest
import sanity

class TestingCap(unittest.TestCase):

    def firstone(self):
        word = 'apple'
        result = sanity.firstname(word)
        self.assertEqual(result,'apple')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, unittest assumes that tests in a `unittest.TestCase` are methods whose names begin with "test_"

Change your test method name to "test_firstone":

```py
import unittest
import sanity

class TestingCap(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_firstone(self):
        word = 'apple'
        result = sanity.firstname(word)
        self.assertEqual(result,'apple')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

```sh
python sanitycheck.py
```

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_firstone (__main__.TestingCap)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sanitycheck.py", line 9, in test_firstone
    self.assertEqual(result,'apple')
AssertionError: 'Apple' != 'apple'
- Apple
? ^
+ apple
? ^


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

You may change the behavior of unittest if you like. Check out the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

Answer (score 0):

You should name the file with test.
example: test_sanity, sanity_test, testsanity.

Answer (score 0):

Your function names should begin with test then an underscore like:

> `def test_firstone(self):
>   ...`